# How to get my $proceed to stop on failure

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to create an upload form that checks to see if a product code already exists. The problem I'm having is that even if it doesn't exist it still ends up being true and
that is because it's being looped over and the false gets over written.

So what I want to happen is when I hit the submit button and my it hits the `$proceed = false` section I want it to stop and return the view with the failure message

Here is my code

```
$categories = Category::all();

$codes = [];
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    $codes[$category->code] = [
        'code' => $category->code,
        'name' => $category->name
    ];
}

foreach($product['codes'] as $code)
{
    if(array_key_exists($code, $codes))
    {
        $proceed = true;
    }else{
        $proceed = false;
    }
}

if($proceed == true)
{
    return view('product-upload', [
        'message' => "Upload was a success";
    ]);
}else{
    return view('product-upload', [
        'message' => "Upload was a failure";
    ]);
}
```

my product-upload.blade.php

```
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">

                    {{  session()->get('message') }}
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a break instruction after $proceed = true to stop the loop.

```
$proceed = false;
foreach($product['codes'] as $code)
{
    if(array_key_exists($code, $codes))
    {
        $proceed = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This stops it but when I try to display the view I get a blank page

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Return early](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.bestpractices.php#standards.bestpractices.returnearly)

```php
foreach($product['codes'] as $code)
{
    if(array_key_exists($code, $codes))
    {
         return view('product-upload', [
             'message' => "Upload was a success";
        ]);
    }
}

return view('product-upload', [
   'message' => "Upload was a failure";
]);
```

this is much cleaner in my opinion

Comment: I'm just getting a blank page and there is no form of errors

Comment: you need to get error from `session()->get('message')` to print

Comment: I'm still getting a blank page. I've added my product-upload.blade.php code as well to my question

Comment: @Nienna opss sorry it is not in session  `{{ $message }}` this will work

Comment: That's what I originally had, but still a blank page

Comment: it is returning `product-upload` view file ? or redirecting may i see you form as well